# Windows Phone Custom URI

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

in my windows phone 8 application i am using custom uri association to launch another application through my phone.

```
i.e

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("sixtag:"));
```

but my app is not able to get certified for store because of this. the testing team tells that you app terminates unexpectedly while executing this. 
now, i don't know how to deal with this. 
is there any way to throw exception if the app which i am launching is not installed on phone ? 
or i should try something else so my task gets accomplished and app gets certified for store as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to wrap your launch in try/catch or check for success as described in the other answers. As soon as you call LaunchUriAsync, the platform takes over and will automatically handle the possibility of no app being installed by asking the user if she wishes to search in the store.

A couple of things to double-check:

1) Ensure that you can successfully back into your app following the navigation to sixtag.

2) Ensure that your call to LaunchUriAsync is the direct result of a user action (eg. tapping a button)

Comment: your second point could be the reason. i was launching "sixtag" in change event of textbox. now, i have moved this launch to click event of button and resubmitted the app. fingers crossed, hope it passes certification.

Comment: it did worked, thanks a lot !! 
further do you know uri for facebook messenger(http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/messenger/3219d30d-4a23-4f58-a91c-c44b04e6a0c7) ?? i searched a lot but i was not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{ 
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("sixtag:")); 
}
catch
{ 
  MessageBox.Show("please install Sixtag from the app store","AppMissing", MessageBoxButton.OK); 
}
```

you can perhaps display another button and on clicking directly navigate to the app store. See if this solves your problem. Do vote it up if it does :)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. If the app is not installed on the device, it automatically displays a message asking you if you want to search the store for an app that will open that Uri.

Comment: I have already tried try-catch but it didn't helped. And yes, i have noticed that if application is not installed on the phone then API itself displays message. But i dont understand what could be the reason for application to terminate unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

You are needed to handle that as shown  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh701480.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) . Also Read out Remarks given there.

Comment: i have made changes according to those remarks and have resubmitted the app. Let's see if it works.

Comment: id didn't worked, they rejected my app with same reason i.e. 5.1.2 - app closure
are they rejecting my app because my app launches another app from it ??